# Angularjs $filter not working with uglify

Tags: angularjs, webpack, uglifyjs, uglifyjs-webpack-plugin

I am using webpack + uglifyjs-webpack-plugin + ng-annotate-webpack-plugin in an angularjs app when doing a build everything seems to be working fine until I hit a piece of code that it is using $filter("currency") or $filter("date"). and the console throws the following error

**Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: eProvider <- e <- $locale <- currencyFilter**

**Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: eProvider <- e <- $locale <- dateFilter**

Comment: Can you post the component declaration where you're using `$filter`. This is usually caused because you aren't using string-injection based syntax, which causes issues when using uglify

Comment: @Tyler thanks for replying I am using ng-annotate-webpack-plugin which takes care of that. Also the controller, services, directives there are all working fine the only problem is with the $filter("currency") and $filter("date") which are trying to get $locale service but this is happening inside the angularjs library

Answer (score 0):

another possible reason is because you pack filter files in wrong order, try to pack filter files before the controller files which is using the filter.

Comment: These filters are part of the Angularjs library and all my libraries are bundle into a single file (vendor.bundle.js) which is the first script that it is loaded.